# Buddhism SE's policy on inter-school communication

Tags: discussion

I would like to remind all users on Buddhism SE that this site is *about* Buddhism meaning that all affiliations are welcome.

When commenting on other affiliations than your own please speak lightly, respectfully and take great care to not offend/hurt other users.

For more information on this sites policy on the topic see our [*Be nice-policy*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

More superior than that we have the Buddha's teaching on [*Right Speech*](http://www.beyondthenet.net/dhamma/rightSpeech.htm).

Comment: Related topic: [Respectful inter-school dialogue](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2104/254)