# Should this question (about the historical Buddha living in Sri Lanka) be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Given all the latest edit[s], should this question be reopened: [Why did Marco Polo say the Buddhist religion originated in Sielan?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/31526/254)

Is it answerable?

Does it contradict the way on which this site should be used, i.e.:

- Question and answer, not "discussion"
- Question and answer, not "preaching"
- Not for "criticising" the doctrines of other schools (this may invite criticism of the view that the Buddha lived in Sri Lanka)?

If the question isn't good as-is, can it be edited somehow to make it on-topic?

My guess is that the only way it could be posted might be as an answer not a question, e.g. ...

> Q: Why does anyone say that the Buddha lived in Sri Lanka -- what are their historical arguments?
>
> A: See [this post] on quora.com

... but that would contradict the "posting a question for the sake of self-answering it" guideline.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be, because it is not related to Buddhist teachings. They just trying promote their own view which is completely wrong and off topic in this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me this question has four problems:

1. It's not about Buddha's philosophy, teaching, ethics, meditation, practice, experience, or interpretation.
2. It looks like OP is trying to promote their own view, instead of being sincerely interested in learning something new - as it should be.
3. Also, the "why they did/said this"-type questions are hard to answer objectively. Who knows why, and how can we know? We can only speculate, while this site is about knowledge sharing.
4. So far it has not attracted, and it looks like it may never attract, an interesting answer informed either by studies or by experience.

The only argument I can see in support of this question, is that it is (remotely) related to Buddhism, specifically, to the history and origin of Buddhism. That's 4:1 against reopening.

Comment: I agree with you sir. If there's the path clearly preached what's the point of finding history? We have a very limited time. So one should practice the path during this limited time. One thing I strongly believe that, *no truth can ever be a lie*. Let archeologists find them. That's their job, not ours.

Comment: nothing else but  he trying to promote their own view.

Answer (score 1):

If this topic is controversial, one of the answers to [Questions asking for an answer to a controversy](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/254) ...

> Instead of changing question to be about controversy it is also possible to just outline controversy in the answer.
>
> Or, answer could state that it presents just one point of view.

... suggests that a way to frame the topic on this site might be as answers to a question such as ...

*Question: Some people say that (the historical Buddha lived in what is now Sri Lanka, and that Buddhism originated there -- this may be controversial -- what are the "historical reasons", the "historical arguments", **both for and/or against** this thesis?*

... but (e.g. as a moderator) I'm worried that even this topic might lead to ...

- "Extended discussion"
- Criticism or hostility (maybe sectarianism)
- Preaching (and posting question in order to answer them yourself, as a form of preaching)

I'm not even sure how this topic is meant to be beneficial, though I guess that's not my business (i.e. it's not up to me as a moderator to decide whether a topic is worthwhile) -- and even the meta-question of whether and why it's worthwhile might itself be controversial or debatable.

Still my personal view (i.e. as a user not a moderator) is that it doesn't seem to me a topic that I want to invest much effort into answering or asking.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a mountain top in Ceylon that has a giant indentation that is supposed to be a foot-print of Buddha. This is the source of the legend.

"Mount Adam, which has a height of 2240 meters, refers to the highest mountain peaks of Sri Lanka. In the dry season thousands of pilgrims come here daily: Buddhists, Hindus, Muslims and Christians – and for some time tourists. Since climbing under the scorching rays of the sun is too difficult, excursions to Adam’s peak are made at night. The shortest way is to climb 1 km and overcome 5 thousand steps."

"Hindus believe that the imprint belongs to their god Shiva, who once stopped in these places, and called the mountain “Shiva-Nadi-Padan”. Buddhists also call it “Sri Pada” – “Sacred Footprint”. According to legend, Buddha visited this mountain in 500 BC. The first Buddhist temple was built here already around 300 BC.

Christians and Muslims associate this shrine with the fact that when the exiled Adam descended to earth, he stepped on the top of the mountain. So the people of Sri Lanka consider their homeland to be the closest to paradise land not only because of the magnificent nature.

For Christian Catholics – due to the Portuguese colonial rule in Ceylon in the middle of the 17th century – the imprint has a different meaning. In their opinion, the apostle Thomas, who ascended the mountain during his missionary activity in South Asia, left him."

http://earth-chronicles.com/histori/the-mystery-of-the-footprint-on-adams-peak.html